# Generate a series of numbers that go up in two interweaving intervals

Tags: bash, sequence, seq

Let's say I want to generate a series of numbers that first jump 5 and then 10 all the way to 100 which would be

```
0,5,15,20,30,35,45,50,60,65,75,85,90,100
```

I am aware of

```
seq 0 10 100
```

but am looking to jump two different intervals intertwined.

Comment: Your description doesn't seem right. What's the logic behind those numbers? What are the intervals intertwined?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: you want the output displayed as a list of comma-delimited numbers in a single line? if not, please update the question to show desired output; also, does the output just go to stdout or does not need to be stored, eg, in a variable as a single string? in an array? something else?

Comment: The number `100` is not in the sequence described.

Comment: the expected output does not match the description: assuming the description is 'correct' then the last 4 numbers should be `75,80,90,95`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `bash` is tagged: Use `seq` with a step size that covers a whole cycle (here 5+10 = 15). Then, for each line, print the missing steps.

```sh
seq 0 15 100 | while read -r n; do printf '%d\n' $n $((n+5)); done
```

```
0
5
15
20
30
35
45
50
60
65
75
80
90
95
```

If the intervals are more complex, calling `seq` that way could very well be nested again inside, like so for this example

```sh
seq 0 15 100 | while read -r n; do seq $n 5 $((n+5)); done
```

Comment: Im picking this as the best answer as for somebody with little coding expertise i have found it works straight out of terminal, as opposed to  getting a script to work (which I dont know how.) and is also the easiest to edit to change the 2 intervals. being the 15 after seq and the 5 near the end of the line, (15 - 5 = 10: 10 and 5)

Answer (score 3):

You may use 2 printf statements to generate 2 lists and then sort the combined list using `sort -n`:

```sh
{ printf '%d\n' {0..100..15}; printf '%d\n' {5..100..15}; } | sort -un
0
5
15
20
30
35
45
50
60
65
75
80
90
95
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- start with `0`
- generate a sequence of numbers by adding `+5`, `+10`, `+5`, `+10` ... until we reach/exceed `100`

One idea using a `bash` loop:

```
i=0
sum=0

while [[ "${sum}" -le 100 ]]
do
    echo $sum
    ((sum += (i++%2 + 1) * 5))
done
```

This generates:

```
0
5
15
20
30
35
45
50
60
65
75
80
90
95
```

Comment: Since you're using bash anyway you could use arithmetic operators for the test just like you're doing for the assignment, i.e. `while (( sum <= 100 )); do`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    for ( i=0; i<=100; i+=(++c%2 ? 5 : 10) ) {
        print i
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk
0
5
15
20
30
35
45
50
60
65
75
80
90
95
```